# How many setState() calls is overkill for Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and reactive programming is also new thing for me.

Let's say I want to build a timer with Flutter.

I add a `Scaffold` with all the necessary stuff in it and I add a `IconButton` which starts the `Stopwatch` and `Text` which displays elapsed time. I also add `Timer.periodic` to periodically (every 0.5 second) update the text.

`Text` Widget controls it's own state by checking if `Stopwatch` is running and updating it's values.

So now let's say I want to have more complicated logic that changes the text based on some actions with other buttons which are the siblings of `Text`. However it is not possible to call setState of `Text` widget directly from sibling widgets. As I understand the point of reactive paradigm is that the state can be passed down the Tree. However if I make my `Scaffold` as `StatefulWidget` and update the state of the parent every 0.5 second it will redraw my entire `Scaffold` with all it's children. So eventually when the `Scaffold` gets big enough it will have to update everything instead of single `Text` widget.

Am I correct? And is there any solution to this. I read something about Streams and Sinks however it looks very complicated and I think that there should be another solution.

Comment: have u looked  Bloc pattern or scopeModel ?

Comment: Interesting article with a few suggestions https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-fast-is-flutter-i-built-a-stopwatch-app-to-find-out-9956fa0e40bd

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to rebuild the whole tree, if the state only changed in a sub widget, ideally you want to call set state in that widget so only that part of the tree (the one whose state changed) is rebuilt.

Streams aren't really that complicated, it's a good way for you to send messages between different components in your app, which is what you're trying to do here.

In your case you can also use a [`ValueNotifier`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html) to store state in the parent widget, or maybe an [`AnimationController`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html), and send its listener down to the sub widget that needs be updated on change.

In any case, the state is lifted to a parent widget, which then becomes accessible to the sub widget through a listener, or a stream. When the listener triggers a signal, you rebuild the sub widget only.

Comment: This isn't important. What's killing the perfs is the repaint. Whis is solved using repaintboundary

Comment: Depends on your use case. `RepaintBoundary` is something to look into, but I would be more worried about unnecessary rebuilds, which is also what the question is about. The cost of painting even the whole screen is not high, and there's additional composition costs associated with more repaint groups.

Comment: I think the question is simply too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Extract out widget and call setState() form that widget  and it's don't render all the widget again

Comment: Wrong. It will. Flutter repaint the whole tree when any given widget change

Comment: i am sure setState() call build method of only that widget

Comment: For build, yes. But the repaint no. If any widget _build_, all widgets _paint_

Comment: @RémiRousselet  ok so using streams can avoid that ??

Comment: No, it can't. Steam are just a different way of calling setState. But you're still calling setState in the end.